# "'str' object is not callable". Is it something simple I'm missing?

Tags: python

I am receiving, this error please help:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\class practice2.py", line 18, in <module>
    kitty.meow('jelly')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

```
class Cat():


    def __init__(self,breed,color,meow,name):
        self.breed = breed
        self.color = color
        self.meow = meow
        self.name = name


    def meow(self,snack):
        print(f"MEOW, My name is {self.name} and my favorite snack is {snack}")


kitty = Cat('Maine Coon', 'White and black','ugly','kitty')

cat = Cat('Unknown','Grey', 'Ugly', 'cat')

kitty.meow('jelly')

cat.meow('meat')
```

Comment: You called a `function` and an `attribute` the same name `meow`.

Comment: `meow` is ambiguous

Comment: Rename your function to something else, or your variable to something else. They shouldn't be the same!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. In the future, please make a [mre]. It will help avoid simple problems like this one, which is practically a typo -- that is, unless you weren't aware that methods and attributes share the same namespace. Also, please use a descriptive title; I fixed this one for you :) See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Don't understand this TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29209384/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `meow` meaning two separate things in your code. It conflicts.
Change either

```
def meow(self,snack):
```

To something else. like

`def meowFunction(self,snack):`

Or change

```
def __init__(self,breed,color,meow,name):
        self.breed = breed
        self.color = color
        self.meow = meow
        self.name = name
```

To something else like:

```
def __init__(self,breed,color,catSound,name):
        self.breed = breed
        self.color = color
        self.catSound = catSound
        self.name = name
```

Two things should not be named the same thing. The compiler/interpreter will get confused and error out.

Comment: *"The compiler/interpreter will get confused and error out."* -- It's not the interpreter that's confused, it's the writer (no offense). The interpreter changes the name `meow` to point to a string instead of a bound method - there's no ambiguity there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class variable `meow` which you defined as `self.meow = meow`.

When you created the object of class, it became a string. i.e `self.meow` is a string. Now you are defining a function with same name which is the error. So you have to change the name of the function `def meow` --> to `def snackName` or something else.

Comment: Wow you guys are so helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes, firstly you haven't correctly passed the information:

```
def meow(self, snack):
    print(f"MEOW, My name is {self.name} and my favorite snack is {snack}")
```

Secondly, the reason why you get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` is because you have created a method with the same name as you passed in the class parameter initialisation which confuses the Python interpreter. This means you either have to rename your `meow()` method to something like `send_meow()`:

```
def send_meow(self, snack: str):
    print(f"MEOW, My name is {self.name} and my favorite snack is {snack}")
```

or rename the `meow` parameter in class initialisation to something like `style`:

```
def __init__(self,breed,color,style,name):
    self.breed = breed
    self.color = color
    self.name = name
```